# R (or Python) functions for time series interpolation

Tags: python, r, time-series, interpolation, moving-average

What are some R (or Python) functions for time series interpolation?

Basic example with linear interpolation:

```
Day  x       --->    Day  x
1    4               1    4
2    NA              2    3
3    2               3    2
4    NA              4    4
5    NA              5    6
6    8               6    8
```

Are there functions that interpolate with moving average or similar functions?

Thank you.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I provided a way to do moving average. As for more advanced method you mentioned in other comments. It could be a good idea for you to do some research before asking questions as SO is not a site for code writing service. Some research efforts with good reproducible examples and code are encouraged.

Answer (score 4):

In R, the `na.interpolation` function from the [imputets](/questions/tagged/imputets) package can conduct interpolation with linear, spline or Stineman method. Assuming your data frame is called `dat`, here is an example to conduct linear interpolation, which is the default setting of the `na.interpolation` function.

```
# Load package
library(imputeTS)

# View dat
dat
#   Day  x
# 1   1  4
# 2   2 NA
# 3   3  2
# 4   4 NA
# 5   5 NA
# 6   6  8

# Linear interpolation
dat$x <- na.interpolation(dat$x)

# View dat again
dat
#   Day x
# 1   1 4
# 2   2 3
# 3   3 2
# 4   4 4
# 5   5 6
# 6   6 8
```

If you want to use spline Stineman interpolation method, change the `option` argument to `spline` or `stine`.

As for moving-average, we can use the `rollapply` function from the [zoo](/questions/tagged/zoo) package. Here is an example showing a moving average with window width is 3.

```
# Load package
library(zoo)

# View dat
dat
#   Day  x
# 1   1  4
# 2   2 NA
# 3   3  2
# 4   4 NA
# 5   5 NA
# 6   6  8

# Create a new column with moving average with window = 3
dat$y <- rollapply(dat$x, width = 3, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
                   fill = NA, align = "center")

# View dat again
dat
#   Day  x  y
# 1   1  4 NA
# 2   2 NA  3
# 3   3  2  2
# 4   4 NA  2
# 5   5 NA  8
# 6   6  8 NA

# Filling NA in x based on y
dat$x <- ifelse(is.na(dat$x), dat$y, dat$x)
# Remove y
dat$y <- NULL

# View dat again
# dat
#   Day x
# 1   1 4
# 2   2 3
# 3   3 2
# 4   4 2
# 5   5 8
# 6   6 8
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Day  x
1    4
                  2    NA
                  3    2
                  4    NA
                  5    NA
                  6    8",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

In `R`, another option is `na.approx` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df1$x <- na.approx(df1$x)
df1$x
#[1] 4 3 2 4 6 8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about some more advanced methods? (i.e. Arima, moving averages etc)

Comment: @mac You can check in the `forecast` package for that.  For moving average, the `na.ma` from `imputeTS`  can be used i.e. `na.ma(df1$x)`

Comment: The zoo package also has about half a dozen other na.* functions. as well. `na.spline` does NA filling splines and `na.StructTS` does NA filling using a seasonal Kalman filter.

Answer (score 2):

In numpy there is for simple interpolation numpy.interp()

If x has nan-values, I would use code, like:

```
xnan = numpy.isnan(x)  
x_interpolated = numpy.interp(Day, Day[~xnan], x[~xnan])
```

In your second set of numbers Days are 1, 2, 2, ... maybe they should be same than in the first set.

It would be interesting to hear about how to calculate (effectivily) moving averages, are there some functions for that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would be interested in moving averages as well

Comment: There was another discussion, rather effective way is to use the difference of cumsums about that, something like this: N=6, Xadd = np.ones((N-1))*X[0], X = np.concatenate((Xadd, X)), Xsum = np.cumsum(X, axis=0), Xfilt = Xsum[N:] - Xsum[:-N]. Same idea works for multidimensional arrays. Sorry that all are in one paragraph...